# Finish my proof that there are infinitely many pairs of distinct prime numbers $(p, q)$ such that $p \mid (2^{q - 1} - 1)$ and $q \mid (2^{p-1} - 1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is from the Romania IMO Team Selection Test, 2009, Day 7, Problem 3. Here is my work so far.

Problem: Prove that there are infinitely many pairs of distinct prime numbers $(p, q)$ such that $p \mid (2^{q - 1} - 1)$ and $q \mid (2^{p - 1} - 1)$.

Solution: Let $p$ be an arbitrary prime divisor of the Fermat number $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$, and let $q$ be an arbitrary prime divisor of $F_{n + 1} = 2^{2^{n + 1}} + 1$ not equal to $p$.

By Lucas, we know that $2^{n + 2} \mid (p - 1)$, so $\bigl(2^{2^{n + 2}} - 1\bigr) \mid \bigl(2^{p - 1} - 1\bigr)$. Then, since $2^{2^{n + 2}} - 1 = \bigl(2^{2^{n + 1}} - 1\bigr)\bigl(2^{2^{n + 1}} - 1\bigr)$, we know that $F_{n + 1} \mid (2^{p - 1} - 1)$. Since $q \mid F_{n + 1}$ by definition, the first condition is met.

Similarly, by Lucas, we know that $2^{n + 3} \mid (q - 1)$, so $\bigl(2^{2^{n + 3}} - 1\bigr) \mid \bigl(2^{q - 1} - 1\bigr)$. Note that $\bigl(2^{2^{n}} + 1\bigr) \mid \bigl(2^{2^{n + 3}} - 1\bigr)$ since $(x + 1) \mid (x^8 - 1)$, so $F_n \mid \bigl(2^{q - 1} - 1\bigr)$. Since $p \mid F_n$ by definition, the second condition is met.

We will let $n$ vary. To generate infinitely many pairs $(p, q)$, what remains to be shown is that not all Fermat numbers are divisible by a finite set of primes.

——————————

Sadly, this last step seems like such a minutiae that it might even be ignored, but I can’t seem to prove it. Zsigmondy’s Theorem doesn’t work because of the $+1$, not $-1$. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5Cmid%202%5E%7Bq-1%7D-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24q%5Cmid%202%5E%7Bp-1%7D-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprimes&p=1) shows [Question on existence of infinite pairs of primes](/q/2928578), but this uses a rather different method to solve the problem, which is why I'm not voting to close your question as a duplicate of that one. There's also the AoPS threads [Nice NT - Infinitely many primes.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1694163p10848506) and ...

Comment: (cont.) [Number theory, divisibility with primes wanted](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2183851p16356890), which basically use your method. In addition, the AoPS thread [p divides 2^{q-1}-1 and q divides 2^{p-1}-1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h478291p2678178) uses several methods, including the Fermat numbers you're using. It also states the source is "Romania TST $7$ $2009$, Problem $3$", matching what you provided.

Comment: Mersenne Prime Variation? See Tower of Hanoi. $2^{p - 1} - 1 = \frac{(2^p - 1) - 1}{2}$.

Comment: Do all Olympiad problems have the same format? You have to know the *known knowns* ... thoroughly (RIP Donald Rumsfeld).

Comment: **Duplicate** of  [Infinitely many primes derived from coprimality of Fermat numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905284/infinitely-many-primes-derived-from-coprimality-of-fermat-numbers) and many others.

Comment: @BillDubuque are you sure this is a duplicate? The OP is looking for the existence of an infinite number of *pairs* $(p,q)$ of primes that satisfy the constraint that $q|(2^{p-1}-1)$ and $p|(2^q-1)$. I still need to be convinced that the OP has really established that this follows from the Fermat numbers being co-prime. [see my comment just below]

Comment: Wait @solasky, why again do we know that $2^{n+2}$ divides $p-1$? I am convinced that $2^{n+1}$ divides $p-1$ but I am not convinced that $2^{n+2}$ divides $p-1$.

Comment: @Mike As John mentioned (via a link), it can be derived from the coprimality of Fermat numbers. But since there is interest in other methods I will vote to reopen it (my vote didn't GB reopen it due to SE bug around tag changes).

Answer (score 1):

How I would solve:

1. **If there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that both $2^{2^{n}}+1$ and $2^{2^{n+1}}+1$ are both prime: Then let $n$ be any sufficiently large positive integer such that $p=2^{2^n} +1$ and $q=2^{2^{n+1}}+1$ are both prime. Then $2^{p-1} \equiv_q 1$ and $2^{q-1} \equiv_p 1$ and the result follows for Case 1.** [Indeed, $p-1 = 2^{2^n}$ [namely $2^{n+2}$ multiplied by many more factors of $2$ [as $2^n >> n+2$ for $n$ large enough]] and $q-1=2^{2^{n+1}}$. Furthermore, $2^{2^{n+2}} \equiv_q 1$ gives a desired $2^{p-1} \equiv_q 1$ [as $p-1$ is $2^{n+2}$ times many more factors of $2$, so $2^{p-1}$ is $2^{2^{n+2}}$ squared many times in particular an integral power of $2^{2^{n+2}}$]. And likewise, $2^{2^{n+1}} \equiv_p 1$ gives $2^{q-1} \equiv_p 1$.]
2. **Otherwise there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $2^{2^n}+1$ is composite. So for each such $n$, let $p_n$ and $q_n$ be distinct primes that *both* divide $2^{2^n}+1$. Then both equations $2^{p_n-1} \equiv_{q_n} 1$ and $2^{q_n-1} \equiv_{p_n} 1$ hold.** [Indeed, as $p_n$ and $q_n$ are primes dividing $2^{2^n}+1$, Claim 0 [below] implies the following: $2^{n+1}$ must divide both $(p_n-1)$ and $(q_n-1)$. This however gives $2^{p_n-1}$ an integral power of $2^{2^{n+1}}$ [because $2^{n+1}$ divides $p_n-1$] and as the equation $2^{2^{n+1}} \equiv_{q_n} 1$ holds, it follows that the equation $2^{p_n-1} \equiv_{q_n} 1$ also holds. Likewise, $2^{q_n-1}$ an integral power of $2^{2^{n+1}}$ and so the equation $2^{q_n-1} \equiv_{p_n} 1$ also holds.] **Finish this case 2. by noting that the Fermat numbers are relatively prime to each other, so the pairs $(p_n, q_n)$; $n$ a positive integer satisfying $2^{2^n}+1$ composite; $p_n,q_n$ distinct primes dividing $2^{2^n}+1$; are distinct pairs and are in fact disjoint pairs.**

---

**Claim 0:** *Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $p_n$ be a prime that divides $2^{2^n}+1$. Then $2^{n+1}$ divides $p_n-1$.*

Indeed, let $b_n$ be the smallest positive integer such that the equation $2^{b_n} \equiv_{p_n} 1$. Then it follows that $b_n$ must divide $(p_n-1)$. However, we claim that $b_n$ must infact be $2^{n+1}$. [Indeed, for any other positive integer $y$, the equation $2^y \equiv_{p_n} 1$ holds iff $b_n$ divides $y$. Now from this $b_n$ does not divide $y=2^n$ [as $p_n$ divides $2^y+1=2^{2^n}+1$ so $2^y =2^{2^n} \equiv_{p_n} -1 \not = 1$], but $b_n$ does divide $2^{n+1}$ [as $2^{2^{n+1}} = (2^y)^2 \equiv_{p_n} (-1)^2 = 1$]. So $b_n$ must be a power of $2$ [as it divides another power of $2$ namely $2^{n+1}$] and must infact be $2^{n+1}$.[Indeed, as $2^{2^n} \equiv_{p_n} -1 \not = 1$ it follows that $b_n$ does not divide $2^n$. This together with $b_n$ being a power of $2$ and $b_n$ dividing $2^{n+1}$, leaves $b_n =2^{n+1}$ as the only possibility.]] So from this it follows from the above that, as $b_n$ divides $p_n-1$ and $b_n$ is $2^{n+1}$, that indeed, $b_n=2^{n+1}$ divides $p_n-1$. And so Claim 0 follows. $\surd$

---

I am sorry I could not fix/follow what you had above in the OP, I was not seeing how your idea could be made to work. In particular, going by the notation in your OP, I'm still not seeing why $2^{n+2}$ divides $p-1$. [Yes, $2^{2^{n+2}} \equiv_p 1$ but that does not imply $2^{n+2}$ divides $p-1$.]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I think figured out how to clear my small doubt. Note that the Fermat numbers are pairwise relatively prime. This is because $$F_{n + 1} = F_n F_{n - 1} \cdots F_0 + 2.$$ To prove this, we will use induction. Note that $5 = F_1 = F_0 + 2$, so the base case is clear. Then, assume that $$F_k = F_{k - 1} F_{k - 2} \cdots F_0 + 2$$ for some integer $k$. Subtracting $1$ from both sides and then multiplying both sides by $F_k$, we get that $$(F_k - 1)^2 = F_kF_{k - 1} \cdots F_0 + 1.$$ However, note that $F_{k + 1} - 1 = (F_k - 1)^2$, so $$F_{k + 1} = F_kF_{k - 1} \cdots F_0 + 2$$ as desired.

Then, assume for the sake of contradiction that $p \mid F_m$ and $p \mid F_n$ for $m < n$. The Fermat numbers are odd, so $p$ is odd. Then, $$0 \equiv F_n \equiv F_{n - 1} F_{n - 2} \cdots F_0 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod{p},$$ since $0 \le m \le n - 1$. This is a contradiction, so the Fermat numbers are relatively prime.

Once we have shown that the Fermat numbers are relatively prime, then it is clear that infinitely many primes $(p, q)$ can be generated, because each $F_{k + 1}$ contains a prime factor that none of the previous Fermat numbers had.

Comment: FYI, there's what I believe is an easier way to show the Fermat numbers are pairwise relatively prime. Assume the prime $p$ is a factor of $F_{m}=2^{2^m}+1$ and $F_{n}=2^{2^n}+1$, with $m \lt n$. Then from $p \mid F_{m}$ we have $2^{2^m}\equiv -1\pmod{p} \;\to\; 2^{2^{m+1}} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Squaring a total of $n-m$ times leads to $2^{2^{n}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, contradicting $2^{2^{n}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ from $p\mid F_{n}$.